# Codeigniter session issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, codeigniter, session

I have a CI application that uses the CI session class. Here's the process I'm having trouble with:

1. Users loads page
2. Ajax request to get record from DB
3. Set userdata variable with that record's ID & do various DB stuff
4. User refreshes the page
5. Ajax request to get record from DB based on the session variable of the previous record (same record can not be passed back twice in a row)
6. re-set userdata variable to new record's ID

etc. etc.

This works perfectly in chrome and FF. But obviously when I come to test in IE - doesn't work.

The ajax request is executed and the first record is retreived. At this point the session variable has been set. User refreshes but the same record remains.

At this point if I clear session cookies and refresh the new record is retrieved.

I've tried changing:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

to

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
```

Like I saw in another post but no luck. Also tried using DB for session storage but still no luck.

Here is the problem page: http://givestream.co.uk/stream

Load this in chrome or FF and either refresh or hit the 'Next' button and you'll see it retrieves a new charity. Try this in IE and it doesn't work unless you clear session cookies.

JS function to get record:

```
function get_matches(){
    var charity;
    var user_total;
    jQuery.get("/stream/get_charity/", function(data){

        charity = data.charity;
        user_total = charity.user_totals;

        /** CHANGE URL **/

        if (history.pushState) {
            window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/stream/"+charity.slug);
        }

        /*****************/

        // can user accept?
        if(charity.can_donate == 0){
            // No
            jQuery('.alert-message').show();
        } else{
            jQuery('.alert-message').hide();
        }

        // Charity Binding
        jQuery('p#char_modal_description').html(charity.description);
        jQuery('.char_more_link').attr('id', charity.id);
        jQuery('h1#char_name').html(charity.char_name);
        jQuery('h2#char_modal_header').html(charity.char_name);
        jQuery('p#char_desc').html(charity.description);
        jQuery('#website').html('<label>Website</label><a href="'+charity.website+'" style="color:#08C;" target="_blank">'+charity.website+'</a>');
        jQuery('#char_total').text('\u00A3'+charity.total);
        jQuery('#donors').html(charity.recent_donors);
        jQuery('#fans').html(charity.recent_fans);

        if (typeof user_total !== 'undefined') {
            jQuery('#total_char_month').text('\u00A3'+user_total.total_char_month);
            jQuery('#total_char_alltime').text('\u00A3'+user_total.total_char_alltime);
            var has_user_seen_stream_notice = user_total.has_user_seen_stream_notice;

            if(has_user_seen_stream_notice == false){
                jQuery('#stream_help').show();
            } 
        } else{
            jQuery('#total_char_month').text('\u00A3'+0);
            jQuery('#total_char_alltime').text('\u00A3'+0);
        }

        /** TWITTER SHARE BUTTON CHANGE URL **/

        var twitter = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://givestream.co.uk/stream/'+charity.slug+'" data-via="givestreamuk" data-hashtags="socialgiving">Tweet</a>';
        jQuery('#twitter_share').html(twitter);

        var jstext = '!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");';

        var script   = document.createElement("script");
        script.type  = "text/javascript";
        script.text  = jstext;
        jQuery('#twitter_share').append(script);

        // *************************************//


        /** FACEBOOK SHARE WIDGET **/

            var fb = '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://givestream.co.uk/stream/'+charity.slug+'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=280&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=119083868224729" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:280px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
            jQuery('#fb_share').html(fb);


        // ***********************//


        jQuery('#char_website').html(charity.website);

        jQuery('#sectors').html('<label>Tags</label>'+charity.sectors);
        jQuery('#permalink').val('http://givestre.am/stream/'+charity.slug);

        jQuery('#refresh').activity(false);

        get_charity_gallery();
        get_charity_shouts();

    }, 'json');

    return;
}
```

Comment: As I'm sure you know, CodeIgniter is a PHP framework. Seeing as PHP is a server-side language, this isn't CodeIgniter-related per se. Instead, this seems to be a JavaScript or session issue. Show us some JavaScript.

Comment: A quick search on ci forums for ci session issues with IE will show you the session library does have some issues. most ppl seem to solve it by changing the ci session configs. I'll put up some js though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed!

It wasn't a ci_session issue it would seem.

I dug a bit deeper and added

```
log_message('info', 'queried!-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Into the controller that does the json response to see if the ajax request was actually reaching the controller and it turned out none of the IE ajax get requests actually made it to the controller.

Turns out that even though the IE network inspector acknowleged the get request it was actually using cached ajax responses.

I added

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

To the top of the js script and boom. sorted.

Thanks to @Laurencei for the help though!

Comment: Thanks, this just helped me with the same problem I was having.

Comment: Yep, after searching for the solution for hours - setting jquery ajax as you mentioned finally get me some peace :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this by setting sess_expire_on_close = true. I solved mine with this setting at config.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set 
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the comment above - this is a CI issue, not a JS issue.

Firstly, IE sessions might also fail if “cookie_domain” is not correctly set - especially if it is left blank. All other browsers will continue to work, but not IE.

Secondly - try this solution:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/203821/

Thirdly - use this solution (which I use - works REALLY well):
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/170123/
(about half way down - the MY_Session file posted by WanWizard

Comment: thank for the reply. I've already got the cooke_domain set. Tried adding the MY_Session class from the second solution but no luck. And unfortunately the file WanWizard posted seems to be a broken link :(

Comment: I've got a copy at home - ill post it later when I get home

Comment: let me know how it goes. Make sure you change your database sessions schema per the comments at the top of the file. http://pastebin.com/p7zM7JTj

Comment: Arghhh, hasn't worked. dropped and recreated the ci_sessions table, which is getting populated. The last_write column isn't being updated unless I clear session cookies and then refresh. Am I correct in thinking previous_id column might be used if an ajax request was made? If so it's not being updated even for chrome.

Comment: This might not be an issue but site seems to default to IE7 standards in IE9.. Change it and refresh but user agent still listed as IE7 in ci_sessions